# Why hasn't the temporary user in RHEL Linux expired after a day, despite the fact that it was indicated in the "chage" config?

Tags: rhel8

[PFA snapshot for the reference][1]

Note:-Temporary username is "DummyUser"
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/amuOr.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `root` can `su` to any user